# Qt. Команды к tittlebar

Tags: qt

Мне хочется узнать все команды tittlebar(там где иконка и кнопка выход, свернуть\развернуть)
Вот, для примера: `this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`- он скрывает все что есть на верхней строке(икона и т.д.)-, а какие есть еще команды?

Comment: не это ли Вы ищите http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum

Comment: Спасибо, именно это

Comment: @KoVadim  А вы можете решить вот такую проблему? Я создал диалог и убрал обрамление и когда я перетаскиваю это окно, смотря в какую сторону, то там сторона как будто сжимается немножечко, на 1 или 2 пикселя

Comment: @KoVadim А можно ли изменить цвет?

Comment: новые вопросы - создавайте новые вопросы.